# O que pode ser feito para melhorar a performance de um CSS muito grande (384KB)

Tags: css

Meu site possui uma folha de estilos, já minificada, com tamanho total de 384KB.

Se possível, o que posso fazer para melhorar o desempenho?

Pensei em comprimir com GZIP, o que deixaria a folha com 59KB, e até dividir essa folha em 2 folhas de 29,5 KB cada. Isso ajuda?

Comment: Você já deu uma olhada na aba `Audits` do Developer Tools no Chrome? É exibido uma série de itens do que pode ser feito para melhorar a performance da sua página

Comment: Provavelmente organizar os estilos é o melhor caminho. Grande chance do problema ser o jeito que a própria folha foi feita. Pode até existir uma razão verdadeira pra uma folha ter tudo isso, mas eu apostaria mais em não ser esse o caso. E o gzip quem tem que fazer é o servidor, automaticamente na negociação do protocolo, se estiver devidamente configurado.

Comment: Se o Gzip reduziu esse tanto o tamanho, é porque tem coisa repetida que provavelmente não precisava ser (afinal, é assim que os compressores funcionam...). É meio difícil responder assim "no ar" o que pode ser feito, mas se você postasse sua folha no pastebin ou em outro site desse tipo nós poderíamos dar uma olhada e, quem sabe, ajudar a identificar alguns anti-padrões... P.S. Dividir a folha em duas ou mais não ajuda, pelo contrário, atrapalha, e eu concordo com o Bacco sobre a questão do gzip.

Comment: Faço das minhas palavras as do Bacco e mgibsonbr. Provavelmente a melhor maneira é ajeitar sua folha, se possível, claro.

Comment: É que eu juntei várias folhas em uma só. Por isso tem esse tamanho todo. (ps: o site é responsivo, então aumenta mais o tamanho da folha porque tem mais linhas). A folha está correta, o problema não é esse. O Tamanho se deve apenas a várias folhas unificadas. Sobre o gzip, eu já sei que é feito pelo servidor, e eu já utilizo ._.

Comment: Eu só sei que gzipado fica 59KB porque fiz testes via servidor.

Comment: Acho que se você uniu varias folhas ctza existe varios componentes em comum podendo unificar no css, mas se fazer isso dependendo pode perder a legibilidade.

Comment: Olha isso, talvez ja tenha visto, http://browserdiet.com/pt/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Um quantidade de estilos como essa deve se encaixar em uma ou mais das seguintes categorias...

## Redundância de atributos

Pode ser que haja muitos atributos repetidos em diversas classes. Por exemplo, imagine que você esteja formatando os títulos assim:

```css
h1 { font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; ... }
h2 { font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; ... }
h3 { font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; ... }
...
```

Nesse caso, poderia agrupar os atributos comuns assim:

```css
h1, h2, h3 { font-weight: bold; ... } 
h1 { font-size: 24px; ... }
h2 { font-size: 20px; ... }
h3 { font-size: 16px; ... }
```

## Estilos muito específicos

Outro problema comum é usar classes sempre muito específicas. Já vi alguns sistemas com uma classe para cada elemento usando o `id` como seletor.

Imagine algo como o seguinte:

```css
#link1 { A; B; C; D }
#link2 { A; B; C; D }
#link3 { A; B; C; D; E }
```

(Sendo `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` e `E` estilos quaisquer)

Se você tiver várias classes CSS com estilos parecidos, separe o que é igual e coloque numa nova classe, então use composição de estilos no atributo `class` dos elementos da página separando o nome das classes por espaços em branco.

Exemplo:

```css
.link { A; B; C; D }
.link-maior { E }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link link-maior">Meu Link</a>
```

No exemplo acima, a classe `.link` poderia conter os atributos gerais dos links, enquanto a classe `.link-maior` teria uma formatação específica para links maiores.

## Falta de padrão

Um CSS grande também pode ter origem em falta de padronização, onde cada componente de cada tela é um pouco diferente dos demais.

Neste caso o ideal é refatorar as telas, padronizando-as em um conjunto de estilos unificado.

## Ferramenta de geração

Outra possibilidade é que alguma ferramenta está gerando os estilos com muito lixo, sendo que vários dos cenários acima podem ocorrer simultaneamente.

Conheço uma ferramenta desse tipo onde todos os componentes da tela são posicionados de forma absoluta. Como os posicionamentos e estilos são únicos para cada elemento da página, o sistema gera um arquivo CSS com uma classe para cada elemento com sua posição e formatação.

O ideal seria jogar fora essa ferramenta e fazer as telas do jeito certo. Caso não seja possível, ao menos divida os estilos de cada tela em arquivos separados.

## Sistema realmente grande e complexo

Por último, pode ser que o sistema seja realmente grande o suficiente para justificar um estilo tão grande.

Neste caso, a melhor estratégia seria dividir o arquivo de forma que ele não seja carregado como um todo.

Coloque as classes principais usadas em todas as telas num arquivo principal, depois divida o restante dos estilos em diferentes arquivos seguindo algum critério relacionado ao uso do sistema, como grupos de telas que geralmente são usadas ao mesmo tempo, tipos de usuário (administrador, normal, ...) ou ainda com um CSS individual para cada tela.

O tamanho total dos estilos não vai diminuir, mas o carregamento dos CSSs será diluído entre várias requisições, melhorando um pouco a experiência do usuário ao acessar o sistema.

## Não se esqueça de comprimir

O Autor da Pergunta (AP) afirmou que o arquivo já está comprimido ou "minificado", o que consiste na remoção de todos os caracteres desnecessários como espaços em branco e quebras de linha.

Mas para deixar a resposta completa, não podemos esquecer de que aplicar a "minificação" é um passo elementar para a otimização do tempo de resposta de qualquer aplicação não trivial.

Comment: +1. Tirando o último caso (dado o tamanho do CSS), acho que tem um pouco de tudo atrapalhando a folha em questão.

Comment: Faltou mencionar espaços em branco e comentários que são desnecessários e podem ser removidos automaticamente por ferramentas como [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/css.html). Tem até uma [versão online](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/) dele.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Verdade. Mas não falei porque o AP disse que o dele já está comprimido.

Comment: Sim, sim, falei mais pra deixar a resposta mais completa até mesmo a título de referência futura.

Comment: Sim @utluiz é um site bem complexo, possui bastaaaantes elementos, paginas... É normal um site ter pelo menos 59KB de CSS em todo o site? Ou ainda tá muito? asd